# nginx, web page degraded when root path is changed

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

I'm setting a wordpress up with nginx.
Everything's seems ok :

- server is up
- phpinfo() test is ok
- the worpress install routine is showing up

The only trouble is the root statement in the web server conf file. 
If I use :

```
[/etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress]
server{
    root /var/www;
    index index.php
    server_name example.com
    ...
}
```

I can reach the service using `http://example.com/wordpress`, now I want wordpress to be designated as the root folder.
Here's the change :

```
[/etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress]
server{
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php
    server_name example.com    
   ...
}
```

Broken! The web page `http://example.com` is only displaying basic html data, no pics, no css, ... ugly.
No errors reported in /var/log/nginx/access.log

nginx version: nginx/1.2.1

What's wrong?

Comment: Where did you put the Wordpress install? Did you move the complete install to `/var/www/wordpress` after you changed the config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also update the wordpress configuration. Without that, wordpress still links the static content to subdirectory. Step taken from [Moving your Wordpress from a subfolder to the root directory](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/329-move-folders)

1. From the main dashboard, go to **Administration -> Settings -> General**.
2. Next, look for the WordPress address (URI): and change it from (**example.com/wordpress** to **example.com**)
3. Lastly, look for the Site Address address (URL): and change it from (**example.com/wordpress** to **example.com**)